# Difference between 0 delay schedule and white true loop in SQS long polling Java

Tags: java, performance, while-loop, amazon-sqs, scheduler

I'm writing a custom SQS long polling service.

Basically

Option-1

```
while(True) {
//long poll SQS for 20 seconds
// process messages
}
```

Option-2

using [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with scheduling of 0 delay. Each task submitted to schedule long polls SQS and processes the same.

What is the better approach?

One overhead I'm seeing with approach-2 is spinning up one more thread and complicated error handling

Couldn't find clear recommendation for the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!